# How to scroll and collapse a LinearLayout with Toolbar in Coordinator Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to accomplish a scrolling behavior with coordinator layout in my application.

I've the following layout structure for the activity.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.Dark.PopupOverlay"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- The layout to be collapse with toolbar -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_collapse_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When I scroll up the recycler view items the toolbar collapses and goes up out of the window and when I scroll down I get the toolbar back.

Is it possible to collapse the LinearLayout with toolbar when I scroll the Recycler View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:context="in.test.ProfileActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_collapse_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
         app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried the layout height of linear layout to match parent. and adding some content in it???

Comment: yes it did... What exactly do you want to put in linear layout. So i can you a sample

Comment: I cracked it. I don't need the collapsing toolbar moving the Linearlayout into the appbarlayout did the work. Thanks for trying though.